# Java ProcessBuilder With Linux CAT Command Return Incorrect File Content Length

Tags: java, linux

I am using the following code to run Linux CAT command using Java ProcessBuilder to return image file content, and I found that it returns less number of bytes compared to the original image bytes (ex: image bytes total are 868 whiles it returned 814):

```
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("sh","-c", "cat image.png").start();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line = "";
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) output.append(line);
    p.waitFor();
}
// Image has 868 bytes while this return 814 only 
output.toString().length();
```

Comment: To read the length in java process is more reasonable in any case. Why start a separate process at all to access the local filesystem..? Anyway, I suppose 'cat' does not exactly do what you need here. To read the file-size you could use the 'ls -l' command instead.

Comment: the image is being handled as a text file (by using `*Reader`) - but PNG files are binary data!  The `*InputStream` classes are used to read binary data; `*Reader` to read text files (including `Charset` interpretation). At the very least, this code is removing line break codes from read data (even if it was a real text file)

Comment: @MJG: I am creating a sort of Linux emulator, and am looking for the image content not the file size.

Comment: @user16320675: Do you mean I should not use BufferedReader? if so then what else I should use?

Comment: @Akkad Yes, @user16 is right, to use a reader will turn the bytes into char, which are a subset of bytes. Use *read* on the `InputStream` instead to load the given bytes.

Comment: again all the I/O classes that end with `Reader` are intended to read text, they include a conversion of `byte`s to `char`s; on the other hand, all the ones ending in `InputStream` are used to read bytes (`the InputStreamReader` is the *bridge* between both) - just use the `InputStream` as returned by `getInputStream()` (or *wrap* it in a `BufferedInputStream`) -- additionally, even for text files, reading a line does not include the line breaks

Comment: Any idea why the following is returning single zero byte only:

 StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
 Process p = new ProcessBuilder("sh","-c", "cat image.png").start();
 InputStream strm = p.getInputStream();
 for (int i = 0; i < strm.available(); i++) {
  output.append(strm.read()).append(",");
 }
 p.waitFor();

Comment: You seem to think treating a png as containing character data (first you use a `Reader` and now you're trying to append to a `StringBuilder`) is somehow legitimate. Why? What is your [goal](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/15-smart-questions)
?

Comment: @g00se: Am building Cordova Android app in which it should use Linux commands (not Java IO) to return file BLOB data as String to JavaScript, and the reason why to return the BLOB as-is and not Base64/Byte-Array is to minimize the String size as Base64/Byte-Array representation will at least triple the String length which causes performance issues in my app.

Comment: None of that really makes sense. "BLOB data" has nothing to do with strings and you shouldn't mix them. *it should use Linux commands (not Java IO)* But you're *using* Java IO already - just wrongly. You're also incorrect about Base64. It will increase the size of the original data not by a factor of 3 but by a factor of roughly 3/2 and afaik there is no more space-efficient way of storing blob data which is *generally usable*